# How to convert Object to bytearray (any object to List<int>)

Tags: arrays, object, serialization, dart, converters

How to convert Object to List (array bytes)
I have instance (some object) from class MyClass and I want to get bytes from this object. How implement this?

Code:

```
class MyClass {}

var myClass = MyClass()

List<int> getBytesFromObject(Object object) {
    // ??? what here should be ???
}

// so I can use it like:
List<int> bytes = getBytesFromObject(myClass)
```

Answer (score 3):

As @julemand101 mentions there are no built-in ways to magically serialize the object for you. Regardless if you'd want to serialize to some String or binary format you'd need to choose which fields of your class are for persistence and which are transient only. You have to think to the core what fields are strictly necessary for reconstructing an object from scratch when it comes to deserialization.

Regarding binary serialization: I try to avoid reinventing the wheel at any cost. There are a few packages on pub.dev which could be good candidates to help you, such as:

- [messagepack](https://pub.dev/packages/messagepack)
- [LEB128](https://pub.dev/packages/leb128) - Little Endian Base 128 used by `.dex` and `.wasm` (WebAssembly) files
- [bson](https://pub.dev/packages/bson/)
- [protobuf](https://pub.dev/packages/protobuf)

You need to decide what requirements your use-case pose and which package can fulfill the given constraints. For versatile and future proof solution you want to look at [Google Protobuf](https://pub.dev/packages/protobuf): that also provides binary serialization and it'd actually lift the code generation off of your shoulders by requiring you to specify the information to be serialized in a `.proto` file and then the [protoc](https://pub.dev/packages/protoc_plugin) compiler generates the required code for you.
My use-case requires me to implement a specific binary output file format, but I'd use [Protobuf](https://pub.dev/packages/protobuf) if I had a choice.

Answer (score 2):

There are no builtin way to serialize Dart objects to binary. But you can convert Dart objects into JSON string and convert this string into a byte array (and later convert the byte array back to a string and convert this string to objects). Both of this are part of "dart:convert" package:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-convert/json-constant.html

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-convert/utf8-constant.html

Notice that you need to manually implement the "toJson()" method on your custom classes. There are packages which can help you generate the necessary code:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable

Answer (score -2):

You can use the java *stream* concept, whitch basically let you convert any object to an Array that you can convert it in a list with the method  *Arrays.asList()*.
 Here's a simpke example:

```
 List objectToList(Object obj){
           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);       
           oos.writeObject(obj); 
           byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
           return data.asList();

   }
```

Comment: Ezio, how can I make this with dart? I am not sure about this. Could you attach an example, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't help you... i thougth you were using java :(

Comment: Arrays.aslist is a static method, you cannot call on an instance of Array

Comment: This is a dart question