# Is there a converter method for the object in firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find a way to convert my customized object in order to send it to firestore.
I tried to look at the Firestore documents but found nothing referencing to flutter.
Is there a way to convert the object and send it to firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Doug Stevenson says in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53538513/13250142), you can store raw data in firestore documents. For specifically flutter, you have to create a `Blob` from your object. See [this for what a blob is](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Blob-class.html). To convert to the `Uint8List` that the `Blob` constructor takes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632438/how-to-convert-object-to-bytearray-any-object-to-listint) converting Dart objects into a JSON string and converting this string into a byte array. It doesn't seem like a great method, but I personally don't know any alternatives. The basic gist of the answer is to serialize the object to a JSON string.

Alternatively, if possible, you can create a conversion method that stores your object as a `Map` and write that to your document. [This reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) shows a javascript example, but shows a similar concept.